# Heroku Master-Slave "Follower" postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I have a small question about Postgresql Heroku "followers": they seem to be a classic Master-Slave configuration.

But I wanted to know if all I had to do was to configure a new DB as a follower of another? Will read traffic automatically be dispatched between the master and the slave? Or should I, in my application (it is a django application), give info about the new read-only follower server?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the application will not balance the traffic. This will be application logic/configuration for load balancing, the heroku followers is just for the high availability.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you tell me more about it ? How do you configure a django app to use two databases in order to load balance? Or is it nothing automatic?

Comment: once i have this question on heroku support, and from there they told me to use octopus (rails gem) for multiple databases, you will need to find some thing like that in django.

Answer (score 0):

Django does "Automatic database routing" to use multiple databases. The default routing scheme ensures that objects remain ‘sticky’ to their original database (i.e., an object retrieved from the foo database will be saved on the same database). The default routing scheme ensures that if a database isn’t specified, all queries fall back to the default database.

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) here.